# WiFi unresponsive following sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi

After my MBP has been asleep (lid closed), when woken, it seems to reconnect to wifi for a few seconds (30 or so) and then becomes unresponsive. All indications are that everything is OK, but web browsing etc fails. By "switching wifi on and off" on the task bar, it then works fine until the next time it's woken from sleep.
I have changed wifi router, and this issue has been evident for a year or so (so was on Mavericks and is now on Yosemite).
It has the latest released version of Yosemite (10.10.3)

Comment: A Console log might tell us what is going on. So from wake time stamp copy some 50 lines (yes 50) and paste them here. In there one can see what is it doing with the WiFi connection.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that but can you confirm what you mean by 'console log' ... Just let me know what "app" I need to use, and I'll sort it out.

Comment: What installed version of 10.10? Please edit question accordingly. I've personally noticed better wifi stability on MBAir mid-2011 | 10.10.3.

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro, and has the latest OS (10.10.3)

Comment: Sorry, not always sure of the OP (yours) skills :) Frist take note of the time you are opening the lid. Then in the utility folder open the app called Console. Then on the left select all messages. Now scroll to the time when you opened the lid and copy the 50 following lines.